# Sending form radio values to Java servlet, returns null

Tags: java, forms, servlets, radio-button

When I want to send a radio value from a form on a HTML page to a Java Servlet, this always seems to be a null value, instead of "1" or "2" or...

Here is the HTML code I have:

```
<form method="post" action="/testWeb/animalsurvey" target="_blank">

<p>What is your favorite pet?</p>

<p><input type="radio" name="animal" value="1" />Dog<br />
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="2" />Cat<br />
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="3" />Bird<br />
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="4" />Snake<br />
<input type="radio" name="animal" value="5" checked="checked" />None</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

This is the Java Servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String value = request.getParameter("name");

    out.println(value);

}
```

Web.xml code, which show the servlet mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>animalsurvey</servlet-name>
    <description>A survey servlet.</description>
    <servlet-class>be.SurveyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>animalsurvey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/animalsurvey</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I don't know if I'm blind to see it here, but what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is the parameter name:

Please try:

```
 String value = request.getParameter("animal");
```

Comment: Wow, I feel really dumb now. That was indeed my mistake.

Comment: It's a common mistake don't feel bad :)